# VS2015 importing color schemes from vssettings files

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Since upgrading to VS2015, i have had problems importing my favorite color schemes from [studio styles](http://studiostyl.es) and it seems that im not the only one with this [problem](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d7cc73ae-447b-4ca3-96b3-b2bde5d8e77a/should-i-expect-vs-2015-to-have-lost-my-color-preferences?forum=vcgeneral)

It seems to have been some changes in the vssettings file format that is no longer compatible with vs2015. Is there a way to convert these old settings or in some other way, get them into VS2015?